# Import a PNG file from within `webpack.config.js`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to add a meta tag to my `index.html` file, using Webpack (and html-webpack-plugin) in my React app.

```js
const ogImage = require('./src/assets/images/og_image.png');

// ...later in the file:

plugins: {
    // ...other plugins,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
        meta: {
            'og:image': ogImage,
        },
    }),
}
```

But as soon as I'm running the project, I get an error:

```
> webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development

D:\dev\projects\foobar\src\assets\images\og_image.png:1
�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

How can this be solved?

The goal is to have something similar to the way `HtmlWebpackPlugin` injects a `favicon`. You just pass a file path, and the plugins loads that asset for you and include it in the bundle.

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot `require` an image in nodejs.